# Checking the stability of an equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I have the linearization of a non-linear system about an equilibrium point as follows

$$
\dot x = (-A+M)x,
$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $M$ has its eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, and only one is equal to zero. Both $A$ and $M$ have real entries.

I am wondering whether this system is stable or not. Or on the other hand to find a counter-example where the system is not stable. For $M$ being a skew-symmetric matrix, then the proof becomes trivial, but in general my $M$ is not skew-symmetric.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude the stability/instability of an equilibrium point of a nonlinear system by looking at the linearized system if the linearized system has eigenvalues on the imaginary axis. You need to go back to the nonlinear system itself and use a stronger result such as the center manifold theorem.

Comment: @Calculon , you are right if the state matrix (-A+M) has eigenvalues on the imaginary axis. But note that is $M$ the matrix with the eigenvalues on the imaginary axis and we do not know about $(-A+M)$ (I guess we know and it is Hurwitz, check my edit)

Comment: Sorry I misread the sum of the two matrices to have an imaginary eigenvalue. Then this problem becomes a purely linear algebraic exercise. I see a problem in your edit though. The matrix exponentials factor when the matrices commute. Why do you think $A$ and $M$ commute?

Comment: @Calculon , first of all, thanks for your time. I do not see where I use that $A$ and $M$ commute, which in fact they do not. Can you point it more precisely where I use such property?

Comment: You need to justify the equality $e^{(-A+M)t}x(0)=e^{-At}e^{Mt}x(0)$. One way to do that is to show that $A$ and $M$ commute.

Comment: @Calculon , this is a property about the exponential operation. $e^{(a+b)t} = e^{at} e^{bt}$. In particular for matrices, you can check it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: I suggest you read the wiki page a bit more carefully. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_of_sums

Comment: @Calculon, you are absolutely right, my mistake. Then I do not know how to prove or check the stability of the system. Any ideas?

Comment: Well since you are dealing with $3$ by $3$ matrices, I would try to construct an example where the system is unstable (it is easy to construct a stable one). If you can find such an unstable system, then you can say the given data is insufficient to conclude stability or instability. If you cannot find it, then try to understand what prevents you from coming up with such an example and try to formulate that understanding in a provable form.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Now I am trying to find a counter example indeed.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Comment: @Calculon , I guess I have worked out another proof. May you check it and tell me whether you agree?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer my own question.

Let the following decomposition $M = U^{-1}SU$, where $S$ is a skew symmetric matrix, and without loss of generality 
$$
S = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \omega & 0 \\ -\omega & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Basically we have a circular rotational movement in the new X-Y axes, with a fixed frequency $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$, and the direction of the rotation is given by the sign of $\omega$. Decompose as well $A = U^{-1}TU$, and let $\tilde x = Ux$, therefore
$$
\dot{\tilde x} = -T\tilde x + S\tilde x
$$

Apply another change of coordinates to $\tilde x$, where basically the new frame of coordinates is the same as in $\tilde x$ but rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ and the rotational axis is parallel to the $Z$ axis of $\tilde x$ . The change of coordinates is
$$
y(t) = R(\theta(t))\tilde x,
$$
where
$$
R(\theta(t))= \begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta(t)) & -sin(\theta(t)) & 0 \\ sin(\theta(t)) & cos(\theta(t)) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\dot\theta(t) = \omega.
$$

Then the dynamics of $y$ are
$$
 \dot y = -\tilde{T}R(\theta)\tilde x + R(\theta)S\tilde x + \dot{R(\theta)}\tilde x= \\
 = -\tilde{T}y + \omega \left(\begin{bmatrix}s(\theta) & c(\theta) & 0 \\ -c(\theta) & s(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}-s(\theta) & -c(\theta) & 0 \\ c(\theta) & -s(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)y = -\tilde{T}(\theta(t))y,
$$
where we have applied the decomposition $T = R^T\tilde TR$. Note that $||y|| = ||\tilde x||$, so if the norm $||y||$ converges to zero, the same for $\tilde x$ and of course the same for $x$.

If $\omega$ is sufficiently small, then convergence follows based on results of slowly time variant systems... but this is quite conservative result, I believe that the system is stable for all $\omega$.

Comment: How do you arrive at $\dot y = -Ty$ from the preceeding?

Comment: @RobertLewis , the idea is to have a new frame of coordinates which is rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ and the rotational axis is parallel to the Z axis of $\tilde x$, so $\dot y = \dot{\tilde x} - S\tilde x$. And $y = R(\theta(t))\tilde x$, where $R$ is a rotational matrix about the Z axis (hence $||y|| = ||\tilde x||$), and $\theta(t) = \omega t + \theta(0)$. The idea in detail is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame

Comment: OK, I' ll check it out.  By the way, are you Max or Emmy?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time Robert. Nope, I am not one of these people.

Comment: Well, no problem with yhe time;  very nice and perceptive question, ***Plus One!!!*** I may post something myself!

Comment: @RobertLewis , I have written the computations more in detail for the "rotational step". I have abused a bit with the notation but It seems working now.

Comment: There is a mistake here. $\tilde T$ is time dependent since $R$ is time dependent. So the linear system is $y = \tilde T(t)y$.